# Change specific value of an array in Assembly (ARM32)

Tags: assembly, arm

I am new to assembly and I was given an exercise where I must do the next:

A[i] = MAX([], [])

I know how to do all of the code except hot to save the value in my array A in a specific position without modifying the other values. So my questions is how could I do this.

*I know there isn't actually arrays in assembly, therefore that is the issue why I do not know how to work this out.

Comment: Arrays are stored in memory because memory allows addressing & indexing (and registers don't); addressing & indexing are necessary for general purpose arrays.  An array reference on the left hand side of `=` requires storing into memory, whereas array references on the right hand side of `=` mean loading values from the array.  So, usually can use the same kind of indexing for both kinds of array references, but substitute a store for a load there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, I was able to fully understand of memory and addressing/indexing. Unlucky of me I did not read your answer untill know, but thanks for the help :) . @ErikEidt